# how to create a custom AWS resource name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, pulumi

I'm creating AWS Kinesis. 
When I create AWS resource with Pulumi, the resource is created with a unique name. Example:（mystream-263c353).

How can I create a custom simple name, which doesn't have to be unique? Example:（mystream)

Here's my code:

```
const stream = new aws.kinesis.Stream("mystream", {
    shardCount: 1
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the full name explicitly in the arguments:

```ts
const stream = new aws.kinesis.Stream("mystream", {
    name: "mystream",
    shardCount: 1
});
```

Note that now it's your responsibility to make sure the name is unique.